# Writing custom angular pipe that extends currency pipe to abbreviate large values while still using core currency pipe functionality

Tags: angular, pipe, currency, chaining

I have some large values I would like represented as a currency but I would also like to abbreviate these large values.

So for example. I can have the following variable containing a number: 342058042

I am currently using the currency pipe on this value: {{price | currency}}

which looks like the following on a rendered webpage: $342,058,042.00

However, I would also like to abbreviate the rendered value to: $342.06M

I could make my own custom currency pipe to do this no problem but I would rather extend the built-in currency pipe because I dont want to reinvent all the functionality handled by the built in currency pipe (locale handling, commas, placement of symbol which could be before or after numeric value, and many more benefits in the built in currency pipe).

I tried to chain a custom pipe (that does the abbreviation only) which then pipes to the currency pipe but the built in currency pipe doesn't accept strings but only numbers.

Also, notice how the decimal value is rounded up to .06 from .058

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One choice is using Regex

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import {CurrencyPipe} from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
  name: 'abbreviatenumber'
})
export class AbbreviatedNumberPipe extends CurrencyPipe {

  transform(value: any, symbol?): string {
    let acr = null;
    let fractionSize = '0.0-0';//decimals for abbreviated numbers
    if(Math.abs(value)>1000000){
      acr = 'M';
      value /= 1000000;
    } else if(Math.abs(value)>1000){
      acr = 'k';
      value /= 1000;
    } else if(Math.abs(value)>100){
      fractionSize = '0.2-2';
    }
    let formatedByCurrencyPipe = super.transform(value, symbol, 'symbol', fractionSize);
    let formatedByMe = acr?formatedByCurrencyPipe.replace(/([\d\.\,]*)/, '$1'+acr):formatedByCurrencyPipe;
    return formatedByMe;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this support different currencies?